# How to use the "about:" protocol of HTML5 in XSLT processors

Tags: xml, html, uri, saxon

The HTML5 draft [specifies](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#about%3alegacy-compat) (at the moment at least), that the URI `about:legacy-compat` can be used for documents, that rely on an XML conforming doctype (which `<!DOCTYPE html>` isn't).

So I happen to have a bundle of HTML5-validating XML files, that start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

Unfortunately, when I use such an XHTML5 document with any XSLT processor like Xalan or Saxon, they naturally try to resolve the (unresolvable) URI.

Is there any way to bring them into ignoring the URI or faux-resolving it under the hood? The try to resolve it happens early in these documents, so for example Saxon's `-dtd:off` switch has no effect here.

*Edit:* The low-level approach `sed -n '2,$p' <htmlfile> | otherapp` unfortunately only works until I start to use the `document()` XPath function to load another XHTML5 file.

*Edit 2:* I played around with [XML catalogs](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UseCatalog.html) and got them to work with both Saxon and Xalan. However, then I get always a

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: about
```

Well, it's not surprising, but how can I circumvent this? The URL should never be parsed, just thrown away.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the xslt? You're going from html5 to ..?

Comment: ...anything, basically. In the specific case XSL-FO to process with FOP (Xalan) and splitting in *more* HTML5 with XSLT2 and Saxon.

Comment: But I'm more interested in the basic "How to get rid of URI resolving in the case of "about:" URLs" than in specific XSLT questions. This is just my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this Java file into $somepath/foo/about/

```
package foo.about;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Handler extends java.net.URLStreamHandler {

@Override
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException  {               
    URLConnection res = new URLConnection(url) {

        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {
            connected = true;
        }
        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new StringBufferInputStream("<!ELEMENT html ANY>");
        }
    };
    return res;
 }
}
```

Now go in $somepath and compile it:

```
javac foo/about/Handler.java
```

Add the following arguments to the JVM when calling Saxon:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=foo -cp"$somepath"
```

Here is a modified shell script script (for *nix system but it it very similar for Windows):

```
#!/bin/sh

exec java -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=foo -classpath /usr/share/java/saxonb.jar:"$somepath" net.sf.saxon.Transform "$@"
```

You may want to adapt using your local saxonb-xslt script if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm stuck with an `Invalid option: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=foo` error. Java version is 1.6.0_22, OpenJDK. The classpath is set accordingly. Don't know if that has anything to do with it: When compiling it says: `Note: foo/about/Handler.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.` which is basically a complaint about using `java.io.StringBufferInputStream`.

Comment: How are you launching your program ? You must not do "saxonb-xslt --Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=foo -cp$somepath whataver". You have to modify/copy the saxonb-xslt script

Comment: `java -cp "$somepath:/usr/share/java/xalan2.jar" org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=foo -indent 2 -xsl stylesheet.xsl -in in.xml -out out.xml`

Comment: Ah, I found the error: The `-D` option must be directly after `java`. Should have figured that before...