# XSLT: Transform of HTML5 as source document fails

Tags: html, xslt

I have no problems creating HTML5 from XML.

On the other hand I haven't been able to transform HTML5 to HTML5.

Such as this source HTML5 doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output
        method="html" 
        doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Brings up this error:

> unknown protocol: about

(I'm using Saxon PE, but think the actual processor is irrelevant here)

Is there an xmlns entry for HTML5 source files?

I saw this related [How to use the about: protocol of HTML5 in XSLT processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917514/how-to-use-the-about-protocol-of-html5-in-xslt-processors), but it seemed a bit hackish, and I also could not apply to my situation.

**UPDATE:** Still working this problem. What I discovered so far, I had erroneously thought that HTML5 was transformable valid XML. HTML5 apparently is not valid XML. If I want transformable HTML5, I need a source doc of XHTML5 (which I did not know existed). Further complicating the problem, XHTML5 seems to be a young standard of limited use. I found a good discussion here [xhtml5 output](http://saxon-xslt-and-xquery-processor.13853.n7.nabble.com/xhtml5-output-td11667.html) .

So, I'm still looking for a solution as originally stated in the Q. However, if that is not possible, my fallback option will be to change the source documents to something more transformable by xslt. But that would be a complex task that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: "*(I'm using Saxon PE, but think the actual processor is irrelevant here)*" It *could* be relevant, because libxslt processes the above just fine.

Comment: Michael.. thanks for the libxslt try. It's good to know it works there, I'll note that for future HTML5 transforms. I regret libxslt is not an option here--I need xslt 2.0 functionality (I cut 2.0 templates out of the simplified demo above).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the problem as I posed in the original question. I could not find a way to transform files with the `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` doctype.

I did find a solution in a different direction. I changed the source files to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, those source files were transformable by Saxon (which I use due to xslt 2.0 needs). The resulting files validated well and ran Twitter/Bootstrap without issue.

I deleted this from the production of source documents:

```
<xsl:output
    method="html" 
    doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
```

and replaced it with this:

```
<xsl:output
    method="xhtml"
    html-version="5.0"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
```

The latter 'output' creates transformable HTML5. I suppose it would be called xhtml5.

**UPDATE** after working for sometime on many use-cases, the above `<output>` raised a `Description: XTSE1560: Conflicting values for output property method` error. I fixed that by changing `method` from `xhtml` to `xml`.